# I am getting infinite re-rendering in React code while using React-Hooks. How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {

        await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/Admin/DoctorList", {
            method: 'GET'
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            setRows(data)
        })
    };

    fetchData()

}, []);
```

This is my code for fetching data using useEffect and then assigning it to the state. This code was working fine before but now suddenly it is giving me infinte rerendering. How can i solve this?

Comment: Just the code above won't infinitely re-render. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (The link describes using placeholders like `setTimeout` to simulate ajax, etc.)

Comment: With an empty deps array it should get called only once, on first render. Please give a [mre]. Also note that it's bad form to mix await/async and then/catch - you might as well just move the promise chain out and remove fetchData entirely.

Comment: Not the problem, but there are a couple of anti-patterns in that code: 1. With rare exceptions, it's best not to mix `async`/`await` with `.then`/`.catch`. The point of `async` functions is that you can consume promises via `await`. 2. It's important to handle async errors.

Comment: Separately, the code is falling prey to the `fetch` footgun -- you need to check for HTTP success (the promise doesn't get rejected by HTTP failure, only network failure). More on my very anemic little blog: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html